Firebase - how can i get data from event notificationclick
I am trying to trigger the event "notificationclick" based on the data value when the user clicks the notification.
The problem i have is that data is null in the event even if the payload of the notification has the data field fully set.
How can i get data from event "notificationclick"?
Here the event in the service worker:
self.addEventListener("notificationclick", function (event) {
console.log("EVENT",event)
event.notification.close();

Here when i get the payload from a service and data has all the property set:
private initListenForForegroundMessages() {
this.fcmMessagesListenerSubscr = onMessage(this.messaging, (payload) =\> {
console.log('PAYLOAD FOREGROUND MESSAGES',payload);
// Notify to interested components
this.\_pushMessages$.next({
service: payload.data?.service ?? null,
message: payload as unknown as PushMessage,
});
});
}

